# Elastic Search - Nest Boolean Field Mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

when I create schema mapping using NEST with my type am getting following exception from ElasticSearch.

```
     public class MyClass{
            {
            .....
              [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed,  IncludeInAll = false,Type = FieldType.Boolean)]
                    public bool IsActive { get; set; }        
            }

private static void BuildSchema(ObjectMapping mapping)
{
    var objItem = new MyClass();
        var baseItemProps = objItem.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (var baseProp in baseItemProps)
        {
            var basePropName = Convert.ToString(baseProp.Name);
            var baseFieldType = Convert.ToString(baseProp.PropertyType);
             mapping.Properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<PropertyNameMarker, IElasticType>(
                        new PropertyNameMarker { Name = basePropName },
                        new BooleanMapping { Index = (NonStringIndexOption)FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed}));

        }

}
```

when I create a mapping with the above request am getting exception. Bool field is not tokenized. Please help me to resolve this ?.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. Can you post your expected mapping in the question? I can then help you create it using Nest.

Comment: thank you for your prompt response. My question is how do we create schemamapping for the boolean data type using Nest.  Building Nest.ObjectMapping for the Boolean type as described above and calling ElasticClient.MapAsync(request). Let me know if you still not clear ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a resolution for this Boolean type mapping that we need to specify 'FieldIndexOption.No' while mapping Boolean type thru NEST.